# What do Wrackspurts actually look like?

Tags: harry-potter

What do Wrackspurts actually look like? Through Luna Lovegood's Spectrespecs or any spectrespecs, like, are they round or square or transparent or what?

Answer (score 4):

This is what Luna sees in the Half-Blood Prince film. These glowing lights are what she claims are wrackspurts.

[image]

Although they're described as "invisible" in the books, this actually ties in quite nicely with Harry description in Deathly Hallows where he describes Luna as trying to beat off *[midges](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ox8SwZCvugE)* when she's evading them.

> ‘That’s her,’ he said, pointing at Luna, who was still dancing alone, waving her arms around her head like someone attempting to beat off midges.
>
> ‘Vy is she doing that?’ asked Krum.
>
> ‘Probably trying to get rid of a Wrackspurt,’ said Harry, who recognised the symptoms.

Comment: Ah, so it's pixie dust.

Comment: @Jenayah - I think this is one of the times when the film needed to show *something*.

Comment: [insert joke on politicians]